# Certificate not found error trying to set up PEAP-MS-Chap v2 authentication

Tags: windows-server-2003, certificate, peap

I am trying to set up PEAP-MS-Chap v2 authentication for my VPN on a Windows 2003 SP2 server using a self-signed certificate. I have meticulously followed the PEAP certificate requirements when issuing the certificate as outlined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731363.aspx) (i.e. subject name not empty, public key algorithm of RSA, minimum key length 2048 and an extended key usage of server authentication). More specifically, using the `MakeCert` utility of the Windows SDK, this is the command that I used to create the server certificate:

```
Makecert.exe -r -pe -n CN="WV21066" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -len 2048 server.cer
```

I then installed the certificate in the server's certificate store (localmachine) under "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities". However when I now try to select the certificate for PEAP in the *Routing and Remote Access* Snap-in, I keep getting an error message saying there is no suitable certificate installed ("A certificate could not be found that can be used with this Extensible Authentication protocol", see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPfnL.jpg)).

Examining the certificate in Windows Explorer, I can see that it lists *Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)* under the "Enhanced Key Usage" property and that its public key (RSA) has a length of 2048 and that the subject property corresponds to *CN = WV21066*.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I hope it helps somebody else. The problem was that I only added the certificate to the "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" store whereas it must also be added to the "Personal" store as well.